# Как достать из Json нужные строки?

Tags: java, android, json, yandex-maps-api

С сервера получаю такой Json:

```
   {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "properties": {
    "Attribution": {
      "Sources": {
        "yandex": {
          "id": "yandex",
          "author": {
            "name": "Яндекс",
            "uri": "https:\/\/www.yandex.ru"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ResponseMetaData": {
      "SearchRequest": {
        "request": "Веломастерская,ремонт велосипедов",
        "results": 1,
        "skip": 0,
        "boundedBy": [
          [
            37.048426749999997,
            55.436448290000001
          ],
          [
            38.175902260000001,
            56.046901239999997
          ]
        ]
      },
      "SearchResponse": {
        "found": 80,
        "Point": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            23.820850969999999,
            53.669822070000002
          ]
        },
        "boundedBy": [
          [
            23.81916214,
            53.668824499999999
          ],
          [
            23.822539800000001,
            53.670819620000003
          ]
        ],
        "display": "multiple"
      }
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "1",
        "CompanyMetaData": {
          "id": "1153226678",
          "name": "Веломастерская",
          "nameHighlight": [
            [
              0,
              14
            ]
          ],
          "address": "Гродно, ул. Советских Пограничников, 51\/1",
          "Categories": [
            {
              "name": "Ремонт велосипедов"
            }
          ],
          "Phones": [
            {
              "type": "phone",
              "formatted": "+375 (29) 785-43-26",
              "country": "375",
              "prefix": "29",
              "number": "7854326"
            }
          ],
          "Hours": {
            "Availabilities": [
              {
                "Monday": true,
                "Tuesday": true,
                "Wednesday": true,
                "Thursday": true,
                "Friday": true,
                "Intervals": [
                  {
                    "from": "17:00:00",
                    "to": "20:00:00"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "text": "пн-пт 17:00–20:00",
            "tzOffset": 10800
          },
          "Geo": {
            "precision": "exact"
          }
        },
        "description": "Гродно, ул. Советских Пограничников, 51\/1",
        "name": "Веломастерская",
        "boundedBy": [
          [
            23.812622399999999,
            53.66493534
          ],
          [
            23.829079539999999,
            53.67470823
          ]
        ],
        "attributions": [
          "#yandex"
        ]
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          23.820847000000001,
          53.669820000000001
        ]
      },
      "geometries": [
        {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            23.820847000000001,
            53.669820000000001
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Меня интересуют поля Name, address и formatted.

P.S Можно пример кода

Comment: Прочитайте [это](http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/)

Comment: кто-нибудь, напишите мне код, а то мне лень (с @Viktoor)

Comment: А почему вы задаете этот вопрос снова? Вы же уже спрашивали это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот простейший пример работы с JSON:

```
{"someInt":"123","someString":"value1"}
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    int someInt = json.getInt("someInt");
    String someString = json.getString("someString");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    //
}
```

И еще:

```
[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]
JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int i=0;i<(jArray.length());i++)
{
    JSONObject json_obj=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String value1=json_obj.getString("key1");
    String value2=json_obj.getString("key2");
}
```

[JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

[JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

Comment: Дальше уже сами экспериментируйте :)